# Merging arrays to form array of arrays in JavaScript (ES6)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an arrays:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Which should be merged with an array of arrays:

```
b = [[0],[0],[0],[0]]
```

To form a third:

```
c = [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]]
```

One way I have thought would be to run a `.forEach` on `a` and concatenate to each object of `b`. however, I'd like this so the list may become longer with, for example `d=[2,2,2,2]` creating `e=[[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]`.

```js
a = [1, 1, 1, 1];
    
b = [[0],[0],[0],[0]];

a.forEach((number,index) => {
  b[index] = b[index].concat(number)
  });
  
  console.log(b);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `concat` method does not append, it creates a new array that you need to something with.
You want `map`, not `forEach` - and you mixed up `a` and `b` in whose elements need to be wrapped in an array literal to be `concat`enated:

```
var a = [1, 1, 1, 1];
var b = [[0],[0],[0],[0]];

var c = a.map((number, index) => {
  return b[index].concat([number]);
});
// or the other way round:
var c = b.map((arr, index) => {
  return arr.concat([a[index]]);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried it as `a[index]` rather than `[a[index]]`?

Comment: @Matt `concat` works with non-array values (like the `a` integers) as well, but I find that confusing when arguing about types.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce()` method with `forEach()` and create new array.

```js
let a = [1, 1, 1, 1], b = [[0],[0],[0],[0]], d=[2,2,2,2,2]

const result = [b, a, d].reduce((r, a) => {
  a.forEach((e, i) => r[i] = (r[i] || []).concat(e))
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```